# Make a reloadbutton on left corner

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, reload

How do i get a reloadbutton on my left corner of site?
I want it transparent and width:60px and height:40px

What do i need to type to get it work in my:
.js file
.CSS file
index.html file

Comment: Left corner = Top left? Bottom left? Do you care what it looks like? If so, you should make an image. Also, is there a particular reason you want this button? All web browsers already have a button to refresh the page.

Comment: No not iPhone webapp that is why i need it.

Comment: I'm tentatively going to retag this with `iphone`, and leave well alone as I know nothing about them.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do, though you'll probably need to change the style in the CSS unless you want the button to be completely transparent.  This just re-requests the current page when clicked.

CSS

```
#reloadButton {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var reload = document.getElementById("reloadButton");
reload.onclick = window.location.reload();
```

index.html, immediately after the opening body tag

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="reloadButton"></a>
```

Good luck!